# How to develop a good model for predicting electricity usage?

Tags: data-mining, predictive-modeling, data-cleaning, bigdata

My goal is to come up with a set of research questions for which to drive my self study into my data.

I have Smart Meter data that is taken every minute, on my home's power usage.

How could I possibly use the time series data on my household energy consumption that would help me extract practical insights from it?

Comment: One question you need to ask yourself is what are you trying to achieve. You sound like those guys in the early 1980s after the Apple II was invented, who were despeartely looking for problems for the computer to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Adding as a answer instead of comment due to insufficient reps. 
Consider developing a model that can identify the pattern of electricity and water usage per house throughout the year. And predict the upcoming requirements. It will be a time series problem. This will help in maximising resource utilisation and better availability of resources among everyone.
Later, this can help in smart power and water distribution which is not yet applied.
If you want a bigger community working into this data set, you can share it online or provide it to [Kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com). Many people are out there ready to help in it.

Comment: Interesting suggestion!  Do you think that power companies already have a decent idea about the daily/seasonal demands of a typical home?

Comment: Power companies may have idea of seasonal if not daily based. But, all these knowledge about demands is known to human. There isn't a system that determines and predicts the requirements. @Gary

Comment: Energy consumption is forecasted in the industry based on weather. When it is colder or hotter than normal energy consumption goes increases. With that being said you may want to also start gathering weather data for your area.

Comment: @KwekuReginaldWade I agree weather is a highly correlated factor. But, consider if distribution can be personalised. Say its a very hot weather, and a house with 3 person gonna end up more energy than a house with only 1 person. Think towards adequate personalisation in resource distribution. I know it wont be easy, otherwise would have already existed.

Comment: Good points regarding weather.  I can certainly try to see if there is a correlation between weather and water/electricity usage.  There is also the field of behavioral economics - so can we try to influence home owners to change their practices based on feedback from the data that is being collected?